Unable to replace a folder on the USB flash drive because the latter is read-only
Using Debian, I "wrote/burned" an ISO to my newly bought Sandisk USB flash drive. It was a success.
The command I used was
sudo dd if=<file> of=<device> bs=4M status=progress; sync

I need to replace a folder on the USB thumb drive with a folder that has the updated information.
Unfortunately Debian tells me the flash drive is read-only.
I have searched the internet for answers and none of them worked.
For your information, I followed one of the suggested methods and modified the contents of the file called fstab by adding to it the UUID of the plugged-in flash drive.
When I rebooted my device, I was immediately locked out of my root account.
I appreciate your help in this matter.

Yes, if you use dd to create a USB from an ISO then the USB will end up in read-only mode. So no, you can't modify its contents. You may turn it again to a normal mass storage device but that WILL erase all data. I don't know where you got your "one of the suggested methods" from, you probably misunderstood something.

Please decide if this question is about making the USB drive writable or about fixing being locked out of the root account. These are two separate issues, your question should ask about exactly one. But I think there is a duplicate of each one somewhere on Super User. For the former: here. Note that the linked answer answers a question where iso is not bootable.

Does lsblk report the device as read-only (RO=1)?

@KamilMaciorowski My question is stated in the subject heading. It is to replace a folder on the USB stick with a folder that contains updated information. Thanks for the link.

So, again, that's not possible (assuming  an ISO 9660 filesystem like in any Linux distro ISO). The question now is why you think you need to do that? This is very likely an X-Y problem. Better to ask another question about the problem you're trying to solve, i.e. the "updated information".
